# wp7 draw image using canvas?

Tags: windows-phone-7, canvas

I want to manually create canvas and draw image into the screen.

set image position x,y axis programatically.

Is this possible in wp7?

tell me some idea to do this.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Silverlight has a class called `WriteableBitmap` that allows you to 'draw' images. The API is *very* basic (just an array of pixels), but there are libraries that can help you with this:

http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/